# How to make mouse pass through window in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

How can I make an electron `BrowserWindow` that mouse events pass through entirely to whatever is underneath?

The window will just be for displaying things. When <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed the window should become enabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> #### Click-through window
>
> To create a click-through window, i.e. making the window ignore all mouse events, you can call the [`win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(ignore)`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetignoremouseeventsignore-options) API:
>
> ```
> const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
> let win = new BrowserWindow()
> win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true)
> ```
>
> <sup>- https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#click-through-window</sup>

I've expanded the example into a full Electron Application below.

Some things you'll probably want to take into account:

- Set the `x` and `y` coordinates
- If you don't set the width and height the defaults are 800px and 600px accordingly,
- If you don't want a background, you have to set `transparent: true`

To make a window "click-through" you'll also want to:

- Remove the frame using `frame: false`
- Disable focus using `focusable: false`, this implicitly sets `skipTaskbar:true`

I haven't found a way within electron to send the window to the background, so if there is a window underneath it, the new window will be on top until you focus a window. After you've focussed a window, the click-through window can never be given focus so:

- Minimizing the current window will focus the next window in the stack, meaning the click-through window will be underneath that next window.
- Unmaximizing the current window will show that the click-through window is on top of any windows that may haven been underneath the current window before the click-through window was started.
- Once the click-through window is at the bottom of the stack, it must stay there.

Such applications are probably going to be started on login anyways, so this shouldn't be an issue in most cases.

#### Enabling focus when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed

I don't think this is currently possible, as it would require listening to keyboard events globally when the window isn't focussed.

<sub>**./main.js**</sub>

```js
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron')

let mainWindow = null

function main() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        x: 0, y: 0,
        transparent: true,
        focusable: false,
        frame: false
    })
    mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true)
    mainWindow.loadFile(`./index.html`)
    mainWindow.on('close', event => {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', main)
```

<sub>**./index.html**</sub>

```html
<h1 style="color: #FFF">Hello World!</h1>
```

<sub>**./package.json**</sub>

```json
{
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A description of your application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/link/to/repo",
  "keywords": [
    "some",
    "keywords"
  ],
  "author": "You",
  "license": "Your License",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.9"
  }
}
```

Install with:

```
> npm install
```

Run with:

```
> npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

A very basic implementation of how you can achieve this.

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow();
win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
```

You can read more about it [here.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#click-through-window)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not complete.